# What's the best back exercise to balance out the dumbbell press from the profile?

Tags: balance, muscle-imbalance

In order for the body to have a balanced look I believe in doing exercises in pairs.  For leg extensions I will also go leg curls.  For arm curls I'll do cable tricep pushdowns, etc.

But what is the best back exercise to balance out chest workouts for proper symmetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say Cable Rows, Bent Over Rows, or Pull-ups.

Comment: I do cable rows, the second question to that is wide or narrow grip, as they both feel very different. Narrow grip seems to  feel a lot better, but then again is it widening or thickening?

Comment: Well, they feel different because they work the muscle differently. The best answer is to do both: Narrow grips one day; wide grips the next time. Change it up. Try not to ever do the same exercise twice.

Comment: Narrow grip should produce thicker (front to back) back muscles while the wider grip should help give you better *lat wings*.